# How to substitute "XXX" | {"Foo", "Bar"} to "YYY" | {"Foo"} in all files recursively in a directory?

Tags: regex, sed, grep, substitution

How to substitute `"XXX" | {"Foo", "Bar"}` to `"YYY" | {"Foo"}` in all files recursively in a directory?

I'd like to use `sed` but the special character here are tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `find` and `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -r 's/"XXX" \| \{"Foo", "Bar"\}/"YYY" \| \{"Foo"\}/g'
```

Comment: I don't think find is a very good solution as files not containing the string will be passed to sed to process.

Comment: @user001: How will you know if you don't check?

Comment: @user001: If you know of some text files that you don't wish to check, use: `-not -name "*.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

using perl :

```
> find . -type f|xargs perl -p -e 's/"XXX" \| {"Foo", "Bar"}/"YYY" \| {"Foo"}/g
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
find . -type f -print0 | 
xargs -0 sed -i '/"XXX"\s*|\s*{\s*\("[^"]*"\)\s*,\s*"[^"]*"\s*}/s//"YYY" | {\1}/g'
```